# Prototype: Difference between these two scripts

Tags: javascript

Consider these two version of constructing object hierarchies in JavaScript:

**Version 1**

```
function Employee() {
    this.name = "NoName";
    this.dept = "NoDept";
};

function Manager() {
    Employee.call(this);
    this.reports = "Nobody";
}

//Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
var m = new Manager();
console.log(m.name);
```

**Version 2**

```
function Employee() {
    this.name = "NoName";
    this.dept = "NoDept";
};

function Manager() {
    //Employee.call(this);
    this.reports = "Nobody";
}

Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
var m = new Manager();
console.log(m.name);
```

In the first version, the `name` property is accessible even though we don't use prototype inheritance (of course because of the `call()` method). In the second version, we comment out the `call()` and define the prototype chain, and yet the `name` property is inaccessible.

This leaves me wondering, then, why bother with `Manager.prototype`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in the constructor:

```
function Employee() {
    this.name = "NoName";
    this.dept = "NoDept";
}
```

when called as:

```
new Employee();
```

*name* and *dept* properties are added directly to the the new object assigned to *this*. They aren't inherited, they are directly on the instance.

> In the first version, the name property is accessible even though we don't use prototype inheritance

Because when you do:

```
Employee.call(this);
```

you are adding a *name* property directly to the instance of *Manager*. It isn't inherited, it's directly on the instance.

> In the second version, we comment out the call() and define the prototype chain, and yet the name property is inaccessible

Because the *name* property isn't on the prototype chain, the *Employee* constructor puts it directly on its *this* (which would normally be an instance of *Employee* but because of how you call it from *Manager*, it's an instance of *Manager*).

> This leaves me wondering, then, why bother with Manager.prototype?

So that instances of *Manager* will inherit from *Employee.prototype*. But you haven't added any methods to *Employee.prototype* so there's nothing to inherit.

Comment: Very nice answer! I thought that Employee.call(this) was simulating the `super()` call of classical object-oriented languages; hence the confusion. Your answer has been an epiphany! :)

Answer (score 1):

Why bother `Manager.prototype` in conjuction with `object.create`. because if you dont use this it will not inherit prototype methods of your base/super class 'Employee'. Normally in real scenario your super class would have prototype methods which you want to inherit and in that scenario object.create gives you a easier way to achieve this.
Consider below example

```
function Employee() {
    this.name = "NoName";
    this.dept = "NoDept";
};
Employee.prototype.method1 = function(){//super class method
 alert("super method");   
}

function Manager() {
    Employee.call(this);//inherit direct properties
    this.reports = "Nobody";
}

Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);//inherit prototype
var m = new Manager();
m.method1();//commenting out object.create will not allow this access
```

Comment: I get it, but why go to all trouble of adding `method1()` to `Employee.prototype`? I can simply add it to `Employee` and make it available to all `Manager` objects.

Comment: @dotslash consider a situation where you have to create few instances of Employee/Manager. In that case you dont want to have a separate copy of these methods for each instance as these methods are not a state of the instance like name, dept. Prototype is shared by all instance and is not copied to each instance separately.